# How does one convert a truth table to a square permutation matrix?

Tags: circuit-construction, classical-computing, reversible-computation

Given a classical circuit of $m$ inputs and $n$ outputs, composed of various AND gates, OR gates, NOT gates, etc., a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) is a $2^{m}\times(m+n)$-sized matrix, where, in general, the first $m$ columns encode the binary inputs while the last $n$ columns encode the binary outputs.  When the circuit is reversible and consists of CNOT gates, CCNOT gates, CSWAP gates, etc., we have $m=n$ as the number of inputs is the same as the number of outputs.

However, certain square matrices can also encode the same information as a truth table.  For example, for small enough $m$ [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) can be used to study simplification of such circuits.

When the circuit is reversible, we can also construct a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), which is a square matrix of size $2^m\times 2^m$, with a single $1$ in each row and each column.  Such matrices are also [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix), which is a requirement for use in circuit-based quantum computing.  Studying unitary matrices within quantum computing is more useful than studying other matrices such as truth tables, or other square matrices such as Karnaugh maps.

> **Given a truth table of a reversible circuit with, say, $5$ inputs and $5$ outputs of size $2^5\times 10$, how can we construct the corresponding permutation matrix of size $2^5\times 2^5$?**

What is the general recipe or procedure for translating a truth table to the permutation/unitary matrix?

---

<sup>Community Wiki</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard convention, a state $|\psi\rangle$ is a column vector and operator $M$ is left multiplied with the state for evolution, i.e $M|\psi\rangle = |\phi\rangle$.

In this convention, the (row,col)=$(i,j)$ entry of M correspond to (output, input), i.e. if $\{|b_k\rangle\}$ is a basis for the Hilbert space, then $M_{ij} = \langle b_i|M |b_j\rangle$.

Therefore, to go from truth table to the permutation matrix, you merely have to place 1s in the right location.

Let's consider an example. For the CNOT

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| $|00\rangle$ | $|00\rangle$ |
| $|01\rangle$ | $|01\rangle$ |
| $|10\rangle$ | $|11\rangle$ |
| $|11\rangle$ | $|10\rangle$ |

The truth table matrix is
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To create the permutation matrix, we just have to run down the rows of T, and for each row read off the input and output, and place the 1 in the corresponding entry of the permutation matrix.

Let's start with a blank matrix, that will turn into a permutation matrix.
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

From the first row of $T$ we learn that (output,input) = (00,00), which tells that the (row,col) = (0,0) must have a 1 in it. (I am going from binary 00 to decimal 0 here)

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

from the second row of $T$ we learn that (output, input) = (01, 01) = (row, col) = (1,1). Then
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Repeating twice more, we learn
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$